# Is Possible to call unmanaged code in ASP.NET website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

In My ID-card read application I am importing some unmanaged code (dll) for authentication. I am unable to import this DLL. I am not getting any errors with it, but the DLL is not getting imported and isn't accessible. It is working in a Windows form when it was done in web application. I am not getting the output. Can I have some ideas or some examples, about how to use it?
Here's my code:

```
 /// <param name="readerNumber">The reader number.</param>
        [DllImport("EIDReader.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        internal static extern void InitSelectedReaderEx(ManagerData data, int readerNumber);

[DllImport("EIDReader.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool ReadSISCard([In, Out] SISRecord identity);
```

Comment: The answer is yes, but to get anything better you need to figure out what your problem is and add this information to the question(exception type/text,...)

Comment: does your asp.net website reference the dll?

Comment: Aniket, yes it is Referred

Comment: Alexei, i understand your's. FYI

Comment: @Muthuram where is the dll file? what folder?

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between how C#/Winforms load DLLs and the way ASP.NET works.

C# winforms execute in .NET VM, ASP.NET(which also runs on .NET VM) is sandboxed within IIS.

You have to first **load** the dll into memory, then call the method you want to.

See a tutorial here [How to Interop ASP.NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eldar/archive/2006/09/22/how-to-call-c-dll-from-asp-net-c-code.aspx)

Comment: +1. Good link/advice to load the native DLL by hand. I'd slightly disagre on Winform/ASP.Net comparison: there is no difference between Winforms and ASP.Net in loading DLL, but rather what paths native DLLs will be loaded from - in case of WinForms default path (next to executable) usually contains custom native images, but in case of ASP.Net normal location for manged DLLs will not be searched by default.

Comment: Aniket,Alexei By default DllImport refers only the Application Path or Else the System Win32.

Comment: @Muthuram for Winforms, default search directory is current, followed by system32. For asp.net it is `\system32\inetsrv`

Answer (score 0):

Is the library you want to reference a COM library? If so, then you need to create a COM wrapper DLL for it. Check out the tool **[tlbimp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)** which will create a wrapper DLL that you can reference in your ASP.NET application.